# UIButton Default Title Color iOS7

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want to know how to change the Title Colour of a UIButton back to the default value.

I have a button that I change the title colour to indicate a something is on, like this;

`[cell.offStateSwitch setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Then when it is off, I want to change it back to the default colour.

I cant figure out how to get the default system colour for a UIButton. I have found lots of people doing this by forcing a particular RGB value, but that is not necessarily correct across different versions of iOS.

Answer (score 13):

Set the colour to nil and it's behaviour will return to how it was before you changed it, including responding properly to alerts.

```
[myButton setTitleColor:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 9):

I assume you mean you want to set the text back to the [tintColor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW1). If you just want the current tintColor, you can do:

```
[button setTitleColor:button.tintColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

However, the tintColor is supposed to automatically change in certain circumstances, such as when an alert pops up. In order to achieve that, I think you need to define your own button:

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton
@end

@implementation MyButton

- (void) tintColorDidChange
{
    [self setTitleColor:self.tintColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [super tintColorDidChange];
}

@end
```

In that case, I propose you use the selected state for you special color:

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

and set `button.selected = YES` when "something is on", as you say.

Answer (score 4):

```
button.tintColor = nil
```

or

```
[button setTintColor: null]
```

> In iOS v7.0, all subclasses of UIView derive their behavior for
>   tintColor from the base class. See the discussion of tintColor at the
>   UIView level for more information.
>
> This property has no default effect for buttons with type
>   UIButtonTypeCustom. For custom buttons, you must implement any
>   behavior related to tintColor yourself.

setting UIButton's tintColor to nil (null) will reset the color of its title

Answer (score 1):

There is no property for default title color in iOS, you can get it simply.

Just define defaultColor:

`UIColor* defaultColor;`  then in your `viewDidLoad` put or wherever the view get initialized:

```
defaultColor = [button titleColorForState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Then you have *defaultColor* as the default title color.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate......

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

cell.button.tag=indexPath.row+100;

[cell.button addTarget:self selector:@selector(changeButtonTitle:) forControlEvents:UIcontrolTouchUpEventInside];
```

then in button action add the following code

```
-(void)changeButtonTitle:(UIButton *)button
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell *)button.superview.superview;
    NSIndexpath *indexpath=[self.yourtableview indexPathForCell:cell];
    UIButton *tempButton=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithtag:indexPath.row+100];
    [tempButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```