# Change Tint Color of Text on UIButton Using UIViewTintAdjustmentMode

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiview, uibutton, tintcolor

I'm trying to find a way to change the tint color of the text on my custom `UIButton` by using `UIViewTintAdjustmentMode`.

I have regular `UIViews`, for example, where I have their initial "tintColor" property set to a specific value, and then if I change their `tintAdjustmentMode` to `UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed`, the tint color changes to a dimmed version of the original tint color. I'd like to do the same for my custom `UIButton` in that I'd like to change the text color using `UIViewTintAdjustmentMode`, but I can't get it to work. Is it possible to do this?

The difference between my button and my other `UIViews` is that I am actually setting the color of the text on the `UIButton` like so: (rather than by using the tint view which doesn't work):

```
[self.button setTitleColor:[ThemeHelper iconNavigationColor]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//where [ThemeHelper iconNavigationColor] is just a custom UIColor using RGB values
```

Is there a way to use `UIViewTintAdjustmentMode` to change text color? I have tried setting the tint color on the button itself and on it's title label, but that doesn't seem to have any effect on the text color.

Someone gave a related answer in this question: [UIButton Default Title Color iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952064/uibutton-default-title-color-ios7) but the solution provided has not worked for me.

Comment: Why doesn't setting the tintColor work?

Comment: I don't know, when I set tint color of the button the text remains white.